# How to declare activity of a custom library in the manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library

I try to call an activity from a library via intent. However I was unable to correct the error of the manifest declaration. I'm using Eclipse and I look for sources Android but the doc has changed, all the examples back on this damned page: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html 
Can you please, explain me how proceed?

I simplified my code to two activity:
One in the project (MainActivity.java) and the other in a library (MyLibrary.java).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button b = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start_second);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btn_start_second:
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyLibrary.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }

}
```

MyLibrary do nothing except setContentView() with a custom screen.
I set MyLibrary as a library and correctly add it as dependency (I can see it from my project).

android.content,ActivityNotFoundException : Unable to find explicit activity class {com.exemple.testlibrary/com.exemple.library.MyLibrary}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

And the anwers is yes :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>        

    <activity 
        android:name="com.exemple.mylibrary.MyLibrary"
        android:label="library" />


</application>
```

So I looked for examples of library declaration in the manifest, but I've only reproduce the same mistakes or bring up new ones.

Sorry for my poor english and thanks for your time. :)

Log error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(11021): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11021): Process: com.example.testlibrary, PID: 11021
E/AndroidRuntime(11021): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.testlibrary/com.example.mylibrary.MyLibrary}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1634)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1430)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3457)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3418)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3660)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3628)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at com.example.testlibrary.SecondActivity.onClick(SecondActivity.java:33)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: add your error logs here

Comment: Sorry, for the ticket, i had simplify it :
OnClick on the main activity button start an intent of the second activity. And onClick of the second activity button start the LibraryActivity.

Comment: Try declaring the MyLibrary activity in the library's Manifest.

Comment: It's already done, i edit the main message with the library Manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i saw it now but maybe you just mistype it, in your Android Manifest

```
android:name="com.exemple.mylibrary.MyLibrary"
```

it should be like "example" or that is correct?

```
android:name="com.example.mylibrary.MyLibrary"
```

Comment: Damned... My french is killing me... Sorry for that =.=
Thank you!

Comment: You should try to use Android Studio. It will notice you when you have mistakes in Manifest. And Eclipse doesn't.

Comment: yah, you should migrate now to Android Studio or IntelliJ Idea, they stop supporting Eclipse ADT now just to avoid problems in the future.

Comment: I know, but i'm working on a source without Gradle, and when i have try to import it in Android Studio, a lot of error appear. So try i migrate it later when/if I have time :/

Comment: if it is still a small project then you can just create a new project in other ide then copy paste it. thats what i do but there are direct approach to this

Comment: It's not :/ 
The project is using some others library with some part in C. And when i try to generate the gradle, it still complain about some error and can't end the conversion.